# How can I use Pyro with gevent?

Tags: python, gevent, pyro

Is it possible to use Pyro and gevent together? How would I go about doing this?

Pyro wants to have its own event loop, which underneath probably uses epoll etc. I am having trouble reconciling the two.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: with Pyro4 it's possible to adapt it to another event loop using the [socket server API](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/api/socketserver.html). I've done this with another async handler, but not gevent.

Comment: @Keith Yes, I did see that. I need help figuring out how I would integrate that into a gevent based application (wsgi server actually).

Comment: Have you tried simply patching `socket` and `select` ([see `gevent.monkey`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html)) and running Pyro in [*multiplex* mode](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/servercode.html#server-types-and-object-concurrency-model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `gevent.spawn(daemon.requestLoop)`. I can't say more without knowing more about the specifics.

Comment: Also, check out [ZeroRPC](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/). Built on gevent and 0mq.